# Editar la Cuarta linea de un INI desde Bat

Tags: batch

Hola tengo este Script deseo modificar la tercera linea de un archivo ini el script que tengo seria algo como este:

```
@echo off
echo [Funcion]>Version.ini
echo Chekers=3>>Version.ini
echo Score=100>>Version.ini
echo StartUpdate=UPDATE_start>>Version.ini  <---- Esta Linea la quisiera cambiar por esta (echo StartUpdate=UPDATE_start)
```

Claro esta sin los () Parentesis

Comment: Necesitas sea propiamente un batch o puedes utilizar un script powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que este es tu archivo version.ini

```
[Funcion]
Chekers=3
Score=100
StartUpdate=UPDATE_start
```

Basicamente debes almacenar el archivo en una variable, modificarlos y luego volverlo a escribir. Este .bat te funcionara para eso, te explico un poco como funciona.

`set new_line=UPDATE_stop`: Aqui almacenamos en la variable new_line el nuevo valor de la linea

`for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (version.ini) do (set "resultado=%%A")&call :sub` : Aqui recorremos todos el archivo y lo almacenamos en  **%%A** y posteriormente en la variable **resultado**

`echo !resultado:UPDATE_start=%new_line%!>>salida.txt`: Aqui buscamos en la variable resultado la linea que queremos modificar y se sustituye por lo contenido en la variable **new_line**, luego copiamos todo eso un el archivo salida.txt para posteriormente sustituirlo por version.ini que es el nombre del original.

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set new_line=UPDATE_stop
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (version.ini) do (set "resultado=%%A")&call :sub
    copy salida.txt version.ini
    del salida.txt

    goto:eof

    :sub
    echo !resultado:UPDATE_start=%new_line%!>>salida.txt

    goto:eof
```

Recuerda que el .bat debes ejecutarlo en la misma ruta del archivo version.ini de lo contrario debes agregar el path del archivo en el .bat